Authentication from IFRAME without 3rd party cookies
I have an application that authenticates our customers via their own IDP that is federated to our application via AWS cognito.
Our customer wants a following user-experience:
When opening their analytics tool from their IDP dashboard, to be redirected to their own web page that includes our application via IFRAME.
The required behaviour can be easily achieved with 3rd party cookies, but with 3rd party cookies being deprecated soon, what is the best way to achieve the described behaviour?
I think that one solution could be to customise all involved apps to use the same parent domain.
Eg:

analytics.customer.com (customers analytics page)
cognito.customer.com (instance of a cognito for customer federation)
provider.customer.com (customers provider)
dashboard.myorganization.customer.com (dashboard that we provide to the customer to include in IFRAME)

This way all the cookies will be shared as a 1st party cookies and the issue is gone, but this requires a lot of custom setting up just for one client.
Is there a better way to achieve this?
